# Uploading Laravel site on server

Tags: php, laravel

I have trouble uploading site to server as I have never seen this directory structure yet and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

I have made a Laravel folder where I've uploaded everything, and inside `html` folder the contents of public folder. Changed `index.php` to fetch `../Laravel/..`. I've also modified `.env` file to connect to the DB. I am uploading everything over FileZilla, and one strange thing that never happened to me before is that I don't see on server side any of the files with preceding dot (`.env`, `.git`, `.gitignore`...).

The error I get is:

```
The xyz page isn’t working
xyz is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

**EDIT:**

If I've fetched the right error, it says:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/cluster1/data/f/r/2129971/html/index.php on line 50`

But I've checked `index.php` and it is same as other sites I've done. Could it be that the server has some wrong PHP version on it?

Comment: Check the error logs on the server to find out the reason. In Filezilla under Server, put a check next to "Force showing of hidden files"

Comment: I've updated the answer, could you check it now? Thanks

Comment: you have syntax error in your `index.php`. Share it too there !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost definitely a PHP version issue.

Laravel requires PHP >= 5.6.4

Upload a file to your server with this code and check your version:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: 5.2.17 apparently. I'll try to look if there is an option to update it. Thanks